Where should I ask questions if the voltage of a USB adapter differs when programming under Windows and Linux?
I have an RS-232 adapter cable (FT232 chip) and use it to transfer data via a Python script. Although I use exactly the same script under Windows and Linux, the measured voltage differs in the data output.
Where can I ask a question about this?
I first asked on Stack Overflow, because I want to know if I have to change something in the program code under Linux, but my post was deleted there because the question is not only about programming. Then I asked on electronics.stackexchange, but got the following message there:

"Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."


Closed question on EE is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/710694/rs232-ft232r-different-tx-voltages-with-the-same-adapter-under-windows-and-l

Just checked [arduino.se] in case, but searching there doesn't turn up any discussion of (RS232 + voltages) and Windows or Linux. It may be worth you looking on there, but since the issue isn't with an actual Arduino.... They cover quite a bit about RS232 though.

If you're seeing correct behaviour on Windows and incorrect behaviour on Linux, with (mostly) identical userspace software, it sounds like a driver issue. Such questions can be asked on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.
